# How can I get javascript code as text from .js to be inserted into an html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new on stackoverflow and I apologize in advance for any wrong way to ask a question.

Comment: Give a brief description of the problem as it is not clear here.Your question contains two part.1) How can i get javascript code as text from .js file. 2) How to insert this code in html page. Not sure in these two part which one is creating problem for you.Also please share what you have tried

Comment: Please create [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: You are right both, my doubt was on the first part of the question "How can I get javascript code as text from .js" I will keep in mind your advice for the future. thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by ajax:

```
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'test.js');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was what I needed!