# Reading Json data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

For my project I've been trying to Read Json data over an URL and display it on a webpage. I want to use only Javascript.

Im new to this. 
Help me out by reading JSON data from this link:

http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

I tried using AJAX after doing a bit of research. Still haven't arrived at the solution:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#retrieve-resources').click(function () {
 var displayResources = $('#display-resources');

 displayResources.text('Loading data from JSON source...');

 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo",
 success: function(result)
 {
 console.log(result);
 var output="<table><thead><tr><th>LNG</th><th>GEONAMEID</th><th>COUNTRYCODE</th></thead><tbody>";
 for (var i in result)
 {
 output+="<tr><td>" + result.geonames[i].lng + "</td><td>" + result.geonames[i].geonameId + "</td><td>" + result.geonames[i].countrycode + "</td></tr>";
 }
 output+="</tbody></table>";

 displayResources.html(output);
 $("table").addClass("table");
 }
 });

 });
});
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where is your code ? Show us what you tried

Comment: Please do a minimum of research before posting here, as there are plenty of threads here and there with same questions about reading json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get javascript code as text from .js to be inserted into an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606813/how-can-i-get-javascript-code-as-text-from-js-to-be-inserted-into-an-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

use XMLHttpRequest, Ex:

```
function getText(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

          document.getElementById("anchor").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

getText()
```

you can use promise based libraries like axios:

add library `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>`

code (basic example):

```
function getText(){
  var response=axios.get('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo')
  document.getElementById('anchor').innerHTML(response.data)
}

getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with AJAX and external resources, make sure you are using JSONP.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: { .. },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    }
});
```

[An example from JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) and an [SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp).  Also a [nice article on JSONP](https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/).